# Is there any program that can open files from Sketch

Tags: software-recommendation, macosx, vector-drawings

[Sketch](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) is an app that's Mac OSX only.

Its used for UI design and my company uses it. I can't run the app in Ubuntu.

Is there any program for Ubuntu that can view these kind of file collections?

It's basically a folder with a .sketch ending containing a "Data" file with no ending and some other stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "these files"? Because you begin the next sentence with "It's basically a folder".

Comment: Updated the wording of the question :)

Comment: Is there any update on this based on the available software for LTS 16.x.x?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Figma](https://www.figma.com/) can import Sketch files. It's web-based and should work fine on Ubuntu as long as your browser supports WebGL.

Comment: But this is on the web. how can i open by some plugin program?

Comment: Very very nice web tools , same sketch functionalities , can import even sketch files and export as PNG and many other features for free...

Comment: Figma is a nice tool for sketch files on ubuntu but unfortunately, there is no way to use local fonts on the web app.

Comment: Works perfect for a quick verify of font sizes, etc. To me, it looked like all my local installed fonts could have been selected as fallback, so it may work now, with local fonts @ArminAyari?

Answer (score 17):

I would recommend a free web-based photo editor [Photopea](https://www.Photopea.com), that can open Sketch files. After opening, you can edit it, save as JPG, PNG, SVG, PSD, etc :)

https://blog.photopea.com/photopea-2-6-can-open-sketch.html

I am a creator of Photopea and I am ready to help you if you have any questions :)

Comment: Excellent web app to open Sketch files! Haven't tried with other formats, since I only get .sketch nowadays for my app designs. The tool could be a bit more intuitive and user friendly, but I have been able to figure things out pretty quickly and smoothly. Thanks for sharing the tool you're creating Ivan Kuckir

Comment: Crashed when I tried opening an average 35MB .sketch :(

Comment: @fgblomqvist it should be fixed now. You should get an option to decrease the resolution, in case you don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Inkscape could do that. To install Inkscape in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install inkscape
```

From **Inkscape FAQ**: What formats can Inkscape import/export?:

Inkscape natively supports opening or importing SVG, SVGZ (gzipped SVG), PDF, and AI (Adobe Illustrator) formats.

With the help of extensions, Inkscape can open a number other vector formats. For importing PostScript or EPS, you need to install Ghostscript (`sudo apt install ghostscript`) and make sure ps2pdf is in your PATH. For formats of Dia, XFig, or Sketch, you need to have these programs installed. For CorelDraw, CGM, and SK1 files, you need to have [UniConverter](https://github.com/sk1project/uniconvertor) installed.

Inkscape can natively import most raster formats (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc.) as bitmap images, but it can only export PNG bitmaps.

Inkscape can save as SVG, SVGZ, PDF, Postscript/EPS/EPSi, Adobe Illustrator (*.ai), LaTeX (*.tex), POVRay (*.pov), HPGL, and others.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: the Inkscape FAQ page talks of some extensions.. can't say if they'll help or not..

Comment: Might work with a export from Sketch, but I don't know how willing they are to do that

Comment: Once I installed Sketchup in WINE... I think it worked.

Comment: Inkscape does not support .sketch files.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that *avocode* finally did it -> https://avocode.com/open-sketch-on-linux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, while this link may answer the question, it's better to include essential parts here.

Comment: Tnx for the feedback. To be honest I do not know what else I can include here :D I have the product name and link to download. If you think there is anything else that I can include please let me know.

Comment: it costs ~$20/month.
it requires sign up. is web-based. the desktop version is chromium-based. to install it go to https://avocode.com/download ; download the linux zip file ; extract it ; run ./avocode from terminal (that's what worked for me)

Comment: avocode trial was not able to open a 122mb sketch file. it choke. both web and desktop-chromium versions :(

Answer (score 0):

You can view .sketch files in the browser with https://sketchviewer.com

Comment: Great option if you only want to view the files. I wanted to see as well details of the design, like colors or distances, which sadly is not provided. But it's a very good alternative to view the design right away.